# swing: appropriate layout manager for simple situation?

Tags: swing, layout

I have a `JPanel` that I want to use to contain 3 vertical components:

1. a `JLabel`
2. a `JTextField`
3. a `JScrollPane`

I want all 3 components to fill the `JPanel`'s width. I want the `JLabel` and `JTextField` to use their normal heights and the `JScrollPane` to use the rest.

`BoxLayout` almost works, except it seems like the `JTextField` and `JScrollPane` share the "extra" space when the `JPanel` is made large.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a BorderLayout. Put the JScrollPane in its center.

Create a JPanel with a BoxLayout. Put the JLabel and JTextField in that, vertically. Put that JPanel into the NORTH side of the BorderLayout.

Answer (score 1):

[GridBagLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) is pretty handy. You can control anything you need and you can control only what you need. You're probably going to be interested in only the vertical parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [DesignGridLayout](http://designgridlayout.dev.java.net/) as follows:

```
DesignGridLayout layout = new DesignGridLayout(thePanel);
layout.row().center().fill().add(theLabel);
layout.row().center().fill().add(theTextField);
layout.row().center().fill().add(theScrollPane);
```

This should exactly behave as you describe.

Each call to row() creates a new row in the panel.

The calls to fill() make sure that each component uses the whole available width.

A few advantages of using DesignGridLayout here are:

- only one LayoutManager for the whole
  panel
- automatic borders and inter-rows spacing

Comment: thanks... when I'm willing to pull in a library, I use javabuilders + MiGlayout, this question was really about built-in layout managers, although I admit I didn't state that.